# Thus there exists non singular integer matrices $U,V$ such that $UVU+VU^2+V^2U+U^2V+UV^2+VUV=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Thus there exists non singular integer matrices $U,V$ such that $UVU+VU^2+V^2U+U^2V+UV^2+VUV=0$ or suppose that $U$ is any non singular integer matrix. Can we construct a non singular integer matrix $V$ such that $UVU+VU^2+V^2U+U^2V+UV^2+VUV=0$?

I have found singular solutions. But I am facing problem to find non-singular solutions

I considered the following: $(U+V)^k=U^k+V^k+p(U,V)$ Now can we choose non singular matrices $U,V$ such that $p(U,V)=0$? Here $k\in \mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary

Comment: $U=I, V=-I$. Adding some context about why you want to solve this will help get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks. Great. Thus there exists any other matrices? In particular, From a given matrix $U$ can one construct $V$ that satisfies the given equation?

Comment: Extending Matthew Tower's comment, taking $V = -U$ will work. At least, it works in the $k = 3$ case you originally started with.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. But I am trying to find a non trivial one. That is when $U+V\neq 0$